# IMAP/POP won't send allow emails to outside with SBS 2011

Tags: exchange-2010, smtp

I have a brand new out of the box Dell PowerEdge T310 running SBS 2011. Our employees at our remote offices can't send emails to recipients outside of our own domain. The workstations at the same location as the server aren't having any problem.

I know this is something dealing with relaying but thus far nothing from any posts I've read have changed anything.

Comment: Why are the remote users using POP and/or IMAP instead of Outlook Anywhere (RPC over HTTP)?

Comment: Outlook2007 and 2003

Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

      Subject: Test 1
      Sent: 6/15/2011 7:44 PM

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

      'xxx@xxx.com' on 6/15/2011 7:44 PM
            550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Comment: @joe - Because they prefer to use the outlook client.

Comment: @joe - And because (I suspect due to the same obscure server setting I can't find) I've had even less success getting a successful Exchange connection set up on anyone's computer outside the office. I was able to connect my laptop is minutes and I have a reliable email connection from anywhere without any problems. But collecting all of the workstations and ferrying them to the office and back from 3 locations hours apart from each other didn't seem like a sensible option in the beginning...

Comment: The Outlook client is the client for use with Outlook Anywhere so the users don't need to change email clients. I understand about not wanting to go through the exercise of rallying all of the laptops together, but OA is a better solution all the way around.

Comment: I attempted to set them up Outlook Anywhere on site, but as I said I had less success with that than IMAP. I could at least get IMAP to connect successfully. I had this exact same problem 5 years ago when we bought our first SBS 2003 server, which eventually led me to abandon it as a possibility back then. Using the identical settings I have working on my laptop on workstations (towers not laptops) do not work. Just as the "Install Certificate" prog provided in the downloads folder fails to prevent certificate errors even if ran as admin. Do they even bother to field test anything anymore?

Comment: My best clue that someone was out to lunch during the beta test is the Help>Settings screen:

Use these settings to access your e-mail using POP, IMAP, or SMTP. 

POP setting
Not available

IMAP setting
Not available

SMTP setting
Not available

Comment: It is not an obscure setting. When you install Exchange 2010 it asks you whether you want to install it with compatibility with Outlook 2007 and 2003 or not. Depending on what you chose there, you may not be able to connect with MAPI from such clients to the Exchange server. And since it is a relay problem, it has nothing to do with POP3 and IMAP. It is an SMTP problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new Receive Connector in the Hub Transport in the Exchange Management Console, modify the Default Receive Connector with the following settings:

- Network: Make sure the IP addresses where you receive mail from are included in the "Receive mail from remote servers that have theses IP addreses"
- Authentication: check "Transport Layer Security" and "Externally Secured"
- Permission Group: Not sure about the requiremets, but I have everything but "Partners"

Watch out that you are not making an open relay. Restrict incomming IP addreses in the Network tab or in your firewall.

I was struggling with the same issue a month ago, and wasn't able to get it working with the instruction on petri.co.il and otherwhere where the instruction was to create a new Receive Connector.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you restart the Microsoft Exchange Hub Transport when making those changes. not the Store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't on the client it's on the server. You need to configure a Recieve Connector that will allow authenticated relaying from external ip addresses.

That's why I was suggesting in my comments that you configure the clients to use Outlook Anywhere as that will allow you to avoid all of the hassle of getting the server and clients configured correctly and securely for POP/IMAP.

In SBS, all of the work of getting the server configured for OA is done as part of the installation/configuration. The only thing left to do on your part is to get a proper SSL certificate, configure your firewall appropriately, and configuring the clients.

Comment: Outlook Anywhere won't work. I tried entering the settings that are working on my laptop into two of the remote workstations. They both claim that they can't connect or find the exchange server. The only difference is that my laptop has Office 2007 and their has Office 2003.

Comment: I tried several posts illustrating how to create a Receive Connector. Each time it completed successfully but there was absolutely no change in the result. I even tried restarting the exchange store each time but no effect. Always Error 550 5.1.7. If you have a link to a tutorial for this that you believe works, post it and I will attempt it again.

Comment: I tried this one: http://www.lazynetworkadmin.com/knowledgebase-mainmenu-6/2-windows/149-exchange-2010-configure-anonymous-relay-to-external-domains

Comment: I tried this one also http://www.petri.co.il/authenticated-or-anonymous-smtp-relay-with-exchange-2007.htm